# Uncertain principle mistake?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I believe I have a hole in my understanding of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, but I'm not sure where it is.

1) Assume you have a source of monochromatic light, a laser, perhaps.

2) Assume it emits from a point isolated to a sphere of some small radius, e.g. 3cm.

3) Assume I can isolate when it was fired to within a few femptoseconds.

4) Monochromatic light implies no uncertainty in frequency and so no uncertainty in its energy.

5) Light travels at a finite speed.

6) I know where and when the associated photons were emitted to within some error.

7) So the emitted photons must be within a region of space having a radius of less than $1.1ct$ where $c$ is the speed of light, and $t$ is time since emission.

8) I have zero uncertainty in energy and therefore zero uncertainty in momentum, yet I have finite uncertainty in position.

9) Does this contradict the uncertainty principle?

Possible sources of error?

Is it possible to have a source of monochromatic light? Perhaps lasers or LEDs.

Does failing to measure in the final step mean there is no violation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the duration of the light is finite--that is, the laser beam is not infinitely long--then there is a non-zero uncertainty in the energy of the light. This is true regardless of the construction of the light source. In fact, the shorter the pulse, the broader the energy spectrum. This fits with the uncertainty principle since a short pulse takes up a small amount of space, and so must have a large spread (uncertainty) in its monemtum (energy).

Answer (score -2):

From the veiw of expertementest, the core explaination of uncertainty principle rely on the argument of instructment disturbence and uncertainty of the measurement, so what you described can't be true. For example, even if you assume light is a particle, i.e. single photon, photon has wavelength, and to measure it you can not obtain it in a point. The measurement is always taken in a range of space, or area. In the modern physics, there's no point object in the world except the singularity, which always hide under event horizon.

From a theoriest's view, when you take the length into infinite small, the space started to feel the effect of quantization. Eventually, you get a dirac distribution of space qubit whcih carry on a region (uncertainy) and therefore the uncertainty principle holds.